# Texturing UV mapping coloring other UV Islands

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have completed the UV mapping for my meshes. Now I'm using the Blender Texture Paint mode and it seems to be pulling all the paint towards the bottom left corner of the UV mapping image. I have selected individual components using the L key but when I apply a fill it colors other parts that run through the color as it heads towards the bottom left.

[image]

I've tried remapping and again averaging the islands scale and repacking, but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the model?

Comment: There is a mirror modifier and a subdivision surface modifier.